# iOS - Dynamically display custom keyboards?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I've rolled my own keyboard view for an ipad app, mimicking the dimensions of the standard docked keyboard. I noticed that if the user last used a split keyboard, it tries to display my custom view at the position and dimensions of the split keyboard, with suboptimal results. So, I've created a split keyboard version of the view, and would like to display the standard or split version dynamically.

The issue, however is setting the textField's inputView in time - the soonest it seems I can examine the keyboard's properties is from a UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame or UIKeyboardWillShow notification - however, this is too late as the keyboard view already seems to have been loaded.

Comment: I've made some headway, working around the issue by resigning and re-setting the field as first responder when necessary. But it feels  clumsy. Open to more elegant solutions...